# Rellich-Kondrachov compacteness theorem for the Euclidean space with Gaussian measure

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces

Let $\gamma_n: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be the Gaussian distribution function defined by 
$$
\gamma_n(x):=(2 \pi)^{-\frac{n}{2}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{2}}.
$$
Let $d\gamma_n$ denote the following measure (weight) $\gamma_n(x) dx$ and consequently $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,d\gamma_n)$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n,d\gamma_n)$ be the weighted versions of the Sobolev spaces with respect to the measure $d\gamma_n$.

Does the following weighted version of the Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem hold?

$$
H^1(\mathbb{R}^n,d\gamma_n) \text{ is } \textbf{compactly} \text{ embedded in } L^2(\mathbb{R}^n,d\gamma_n).
$$

Comment: If $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n,d\gamma_n)$, have you considered whether or not $e^{-|x|^2/4}f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Not sure if that leads where you want or not, but it's something to consider.

Comment: How do you define the weighted Sobolev space?